# How do I decrypt an encoded VPN pre-shared key?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, vpn

I have a windows 7 *.cmp file which contains an encrypted pre-shred key in it and I also know the pin-code for it.

```
[Profile Format]
Version=5

[Connection Manager]
CMSFile=xxx\yyy.cms
PresharedKey=*************==
PresharedKeyIsEncrypted=1
```

The question is what do I use to decrypt the key and view it in plaintext?